# Making a Python 2.7 module: Referencing values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I'm making a fairly simple weather module for myself and I have run into a major issue, I can't get a value from my module.

First, let me show you what I have so I can point out my issue.

PyWeather.py:

```
import urllib2
import json
import time

class get:
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.location = location

    def status(self):
        input = self.location

        fixedinput = input.replace(" ","%20")

        response = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + fixedinput)

        data = json.load(response)

        weather = data['weather'][0]['main']

        return weather
```

Main.py:

```
import PyWeather

location = 'Lexington, SC'

current = PyWeather.get(location).status

print current
```

I'm a little more than a beginner in Python, but I taught myself, so I don't understand quite a bit.

My issue lies in the output:

```
<bound method get.status of <PyWeather.get instance at 0x01925940>>
```

How do I get an output such as 'Clouds' (Which is the current condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the function. You are just creating an alias to the function using the `current` variable name. Try

```
current = PyWeather.get(location).status() # Notice the ()
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm a little dumb. That worked nicely thank you.

Answer (score 0):

current = PyWeather.get(location).status()

should fix the issue

Comment: ...said @SukritKalra 10 minutes ago. :)

Comment: opss ... didn't see that